# Use Tab(or any other shortcut) to select word suggested in Touch Bar?

Tags: macos, touch-bar

I m using a note taking app. While typing, Touch Bar suggest 3 words with the middle one being blue. Is there anyway I can just type half word and press any button like `Tab` and the word is auto-filled?

Please let me know if any more clarity is required.

Comment: Someone may need to confirm this [I have no touch bar] but if it's anything like iOS, **if** the word is clearly highlighted rather than being one of several non-highlighted options, then tapping Spacebar will fill the word & move on ready for your next word.

Comment: No that doesn't work on Mac. It adds actual space.

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry. Worth a shot I guess;) Wish you luck.